# Get response from AJAX/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

While I am very new to `AJAX`, I really don't know why this wouldn't be working correctly. I have a table that is made editable through a click eventlistener, then there is another event listener listening for a keypress of the enter key and when that happens gets different variables and sends an AJAX post request to the server. But, when I press enter, nothing happens. By nothing happens, I mean I stay on the page I was on instead of the PHP functions on the server directing me elsewhere. What's odd is that after my `ajax.send(vars)`, I console.logged out my `ajax` object and the response showed an HTML page being served, but:
1. It showed the response I would get if my ID, loc, or column values were empty (which, when I logged those variables out, they were not)
2. That page wasn't being served. The ajax object showed the response, but I (the end user) wasn't seeing that response.
Here is my JavaScript:

```
        index.addEventListener("keypress", function(e){
        var key = e.keyCode;
            if (key === 13) {
                var entry = e.path[0].innerText;
                var tabID = e.path[1].id;
                var table = tabID.charAt(0);
                if (table === 'o') {
                    table = "otheraccounts";
                } if (table === 'wh') {
                    table = "wheatstoneaccounts";
                } if (table === 'wo') {
                    table = "wideorbitaccounts";
                }
                var ID = tabID.charAt(1);
                var column = e.path[0].id;
                var loc = e.path[3].getElementsByTagName("input").location.value;
                var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
                ajax.open("post", "../other/index.php?action=updateTable", true);
                ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                ajax.send(entry, table, ID, column, loc);
            }
    }, false)
```

And here is the `PHP`:

```
case 'updateTable':
    $column = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'column', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $ID = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ID', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $table = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'table', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $entry = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'entry', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $location = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'loc', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    if (empty($ID) || empty($column) || empty($table)){
        $message = "<p class='message'>Stop tampering with my IDs!!</p>";
        $_SESSION['message'] = $message;
        header("Location: /radiosite/other/index.php?action=$location");
        exit;
    }
    $result = updateEntry($column, $ID, $table, $entry);
    if ($result === 1) {
        $message = "<p class='message'>The entry was successfully updated in the database</p>";
        $_SESSION['message'] = $message;
        header("Location: /radiosite/other/index.php?action=$location");
        exit;
    } else {
        $message = "<p class='message'>Nothing was added to the database</p>";
        $_SESSION['message'] = $message;
        header("Location: /radiosite/other/index.php?action=$location");    
        exit;            
    }
break;
```

Comment: You don't have a callback function that processes the response from the AJAX. And `ajax.send(entry, table, ID, column, loc);` is not the correct way to send the parameters.

Comment: You can't use `header("Location")` to redirect after an AJAX request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX won't redirect the browser when it gets a redirection header. That just tells it to go to that alternate URL to get the response data.

Change the PHP so it returns the new URL as a string. Change lines like:

```
header("Location: /radiosite/other/index.php?action=$location");
```

to:

```
echo "/radiosite/other/index.php?action=$location";
```

Then in the Javascript code you can read the response and assign it to `window.location` to perform the redirection.

You're also not sending the POST parameters properly. You need to construct the URL-encoded string.

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("post", "../other/index.php?action=updateTable", true);
ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
ajax.send('entry=' + encodeURIComponent(entry) + '&table=' + encodeURIComponent(table) + '&ID=' + encodeURIComponent(ID) + '&column=' + encodeURIComponent(column) + '&loc=' + encodeURIComponent(loc));
ajax.onload = function() {
    window.location = ajax.responseText.trim();
};
```

Comment: Thank you! Turns out I truly understood zero AJAX. I need to read up on that. I've also got to hunt down a SQL error because MariaDB apparently doesn't like that I'm passing a table name through as a bound variable.

Comment: @AdamMcGurk Bound variables can only be used where expressions are allowed, they can't be used for table or column names.

Comment: Afer some hunting around, I found that out. So, since I knew my table and column names, I just sent the input through a switch statement, so the input would have to be identically equal, or produce an error message. Thanks!